# Using Firebase Hosting to deploy the angular application

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material2, firebase-hosting

I have created a simple application in Angular2("angular-material"). I am trying to deploy the application using Firebase Hosting.

Initially I started with "npm install" and served my application successfully using "ng s".

Next from within my Angular2 application("angular-material") I started with typing the command "firebase login" and I successfully logged in through my google account.

Then I tried to build my app using "ng build" command. And it was successful.

Then I tried "firebase init" command as shown below

[image]

But when I proceed further with the Hosting option , I am unable to get my application in the listing from where I can select my project for Hosting.

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command `firebase use --add` for listing Your Project.

Comment: using this command is listing only "fir-demo-project" and no other projects

Comment: please help me in solving this issue